# Predatory math journals

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, education, math-history

Are those papers in math which are published in predatory journals (those which are in the Beall's list) credible? Are the results published in those journals generally accepted in the mathematics community? I hope you can help me on this since I am planning to submit a paper in a math journal.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question.  How about, instead, "Is it ethical to submit papers to unethical journals?" Then the answer is easy.

Comment: some sort of. is it OK? i've seen a lot of good papers in math which were published in predatory mathematics journals, but unfortunately, the authors' choices are wrong. they should have chosen a more reputable journal.

Comment: Can you provide a link for Beall's list?

Comment: @MikhailKatz you can just google it.